# How to add transition to CSS3 Animation steps

Tags: animation, css

I have some images that i want to appear automatically one by one using just css. I am using to animation for that. This is working fine.

> http://jsfiddle.net/vinnizworld/Sap24/

But how could i add transition to each step of animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@-webkit-keyframes move{
  0%{ margin-left: 0;  }
  10%{    margin-left: -440px;  }
  100%{    margin-left: -5440px;  }
}
```

`from` and `to` are convenient keyword, but using `%` you can add as many steps as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is that you want http://jsfiddle.net/Sap24/2/ . Write like this:

```
.img-wrapper{
            width: 9999px;
            margin-left: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            -webkit-animation:move 25s linear infinite;
        }
```